# Why can't I make a request with SessionManager in Alamofire 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

just upgraded to Alamofire 4.0 for Swift 3.0 support. I was previously using a `Manager` object and making all requests from there. This `Manager` object has since been renamed to `SessionManager` however there are no `request` methods there anymore. Why is this? If I instead use `Alamofire.request` to make my requests then how do I use the session managers configuration with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use SessionManager.request.  From the [docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager):

> Top-level convenience methods like Alamofire.request use a default
>   instance of Alamofire.SessionManager, which is configured with the
>   default URLSessionConfiguration.
>
> As such, the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> ```
> Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get") 
>
> let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
> sessionManager.request("https://httpbin.org/get")
> ```